# NullInjectorError: No provider for OidcDataService

Tags: angular, openid, angular5

I am new to OpenID and Angular, and am trying to make use of the `angular-auth-oidc-client` package. There are some great examples by [damienbod](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow.git) and  [elanderson](https://github.com/elanderson/Angular-Core-IdentityServer), but I can't even seem to get off the starting block.

After installing the package, all I have to do is inject the `OidcSecurityService` - I don't have to use it even - and I am getting a runtime error:

```
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[OidcSecurityService -> OidcDataService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[OidcSecurityService ->  OidcDataService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for OidcDataService!
...
```

My natural thought was to import `OidcDataService` and add it to the providers, but that results in a compiler error:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(3,31): error TS2305: 
  Module '"<...>/auth-test/node_modules/angular-auth-oidc-client/index"' 
    has no exported member 'OidcDataService'.
```

My Google-fu has uncovered nothing that appears relevant, and it is blocking so early in the process of integrating the package, that I must be making a bad assumption somewhere about how to link everything together. Can anyone see it?

## Reproducing

I can reproduce with a minimal project. Create the project with these steps:

```
ng new auth-test
npm install angular-auth-oidc-client --save
```

Then add the Oidc services so that `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  providers: [ OidcSecurityService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
      private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService
  ) {
    // I would configure my STS Server, etc, if I could just get past this bug.
  }
}
```

Then just serve it up and view the console for the runtime error.

```
ng serve
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK. I think I see where I went wrong. The samples are good, but they have enough complexity that that I didn't consider that the `AuthModule` was part of the package. I thought it was something the samples build *around* the package. The brief example in the [angular-auth-oidc-client README](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/master/README.md) set me on the right track

So `AuthModule` needs to be imported (my larger, real project did), but it also needs a call to `AuthModule.forRoot()` to be included in the `AppModule` `imports` metadata (my larger, real project did not).

So with those updates, `app.module.ts` now looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthModule, OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([{path: "", component:AppComponent}])

  ],
  providers: [OidcSecurityService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
      private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService
  ) {
    // Now I can configure my STS Server, and off I go.
  }
}
```

And works. Note the addition of the `RouterModule`, as well, which the `AuthModule` depends on, and it's `.forRoot()`, both of which also were in my real project, but needed to be added to this minimal proof-of-concept.

It became apparent to me that there was a hole in my understanding around `.forRoot()`. In short, we need to make sure that the things the AuthModule provides are provided to the whole rest of the App.

I found [this article](http://angularfirst.com/the-ngmodule-forroot-convention/) helpful in filling in that hole.